# GAE middlewares for modules?

Tags: google-app-engine, middleware, google-app-engine-python

Assume that I have few modules on my GAE project (say A, B, C). They shares the users database and sessions.

For example: module A will manage the login/logout actions (through cookies), module B,C will handle other actions. FYI, those modules are developed in both PHP and Python.

Now, I do not want to make user & session verification codes on all 3 modules.

Is there anyway for me to put a middleware that run before all 3 modules for each request. Such as X: it will add header for each request to set the user id and some user's information if the user has logged in.

I.E: after I can implement my above idea. Each request will run through 1 in below 3 cases:

- X, A
- X, B
- X, C

What do you say?
Thanks

#### Update 1: more information

The middleware, I mean the request middle ware.

If X is a middleware then it will be run before the request is passed to the app (or module), it will change the request only such as:

- Do some authentication actions
- Add some headers:

  - `X-User-Id`: for authorized user id
  - `X-User-Scopes`: for scopes of authorized user
- etc ...

And of course, it is independent to the inside module's language (PHP or Python or Java or ...)

The X middleware should be configured at `app.yaml`.

Comment: why not another module?

Comment: Suppose that X is another module, how can I pass the request next to A, B or C module?

Answer (score 0):

The way I approached such scenario (in a python-only project, donno about php) was to use a custom handler (inheriting webapp2.RequestHandler which I was already using for session support). In its customized dispatch() method the user info is collected and stored in the handler object itself.

The implementation of the handler exists in only one version controlled file, but which is symlinked (for GAE accessibility) in each module that references the handler. This way I don't have to manage multiple independent copies of the user and session verification code.

Comment: Oh, if the project is python only, we can use your solution by building a wsgi app that pass the request to some wsgi apps inside. My problem is my current code base has been written in PHP, I am moving some parts to python.

Comment: Right, you'd probably need a master copy for each language, symlinked into the respective language modules for sharing the code.

Comment: Now that you mention it even with a middleware approach - you'd still need one middleware for each language since each module executes into an app engine instance running the respective language sandbox.

Comment: I am sorry for this late reply. I have edited my question to give more details about my idea. I'm looking for a way to config this middleware at app.yaml, so this middleware will run at every instance, independent to the instance's language.

Comment: I don't think this is possible: the app.yaml file is not 100% independent of the language sandbox of the module, which is why there are different language-specific guides for it (for example the java one doesn't even use an app.yaml file). In addition I don't see in any of the guides a way to handle a route other than statically or via an app script implemented in the respective language.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just looking for a similar solution for my situation. It doesn't have to exactly be middleware or something like that. Do you have any idea?